# FormIt - redirect hook issue

Tags: modx-revolution, formit

**ISSUE**:  I'm using FormIt and the redirect hook is not working for me.

It is redirecting to http://www.example.comPageName.html instead of http://www.example.com/PageName.html. It is not placing the forward slash after the page name.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Here is my FormIt snippet.

```
[[!FormIt? &hooks=`email,redirect` &emailTpl=`MyEmailChunk` &emailTo=`mypersonalemail@email.com` &emailSubject=`Contact Us form submission` &redirectTo=`35` &emailFrom=`info@domainnamme.com`]]
```

- Yes, the MyEmailChunk exists.
- The email addresses are dummy values
- The resource with id 35 is in the same context and is published and is hidden from the menus.
- I'm using friendly urls.
- If I try another resource it works.

Answer (score 1):

URL generated in the following code

```
$url = $this->modx->makeUrl($this->formit->config['redirectTo'],$contextKey,$redirectParams,'full');
```

`'full'` means `URL is absolute, prepended with site_url from config` ( http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modX.makeUrl ). Please check your `site_url` variable in `/core/config/config.inc.php`

Comment: What am I suppose to be looking for in particular?  I can see the code that sets the site_url;   $site_url= $url_scheme . $http_host . MODX_BASE_URL;.

$http_host is defined correctly but it doesn't have a forward slash at the end of it.   Should it?

Comment: What is the value of `MODX_BASE_URL` ? Looks like a problem with it.

Comment: The value of MODX_BASE_URL is $modx_base_url= '/';.   Is that correct?

Comment: http://forums.modx.com/thread/47544/formit-not-redirecting-properly-rc2?page=2#dis-post-460237 - here is solution

Comment: Thanks for your response and input.   Unfortunately nothing helped me.  I will try to roll my own form response handling code :(.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the site_url variable needs to be checked in the System Settings.

Make sure you have a trailing slash.